# Mongodb : Distribution of collections using sharding

Tags: mongodb, bson

The application that we developed is a data crunching application and in this process, there will multiple collections that are created. So, there is a high chance that the maximum limit of 3 million collections (provided we use all the 2GB provided for NS) will be crossed.
Can I have different collections distributed in different mongodb instances and manage them using sharding ?

Comment: 3 million collections? I smell a rat here.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev : I do accept 3 million collections is a bad idea. But, we are dealing with time-series data which gets logged from different data sources which gets added up with time. We tried without distributing the data into different collections and querying them using a unique key. But that proved to be a bitch on performance because there are multiple io operations on the same set of collections every sec. We distributed them into different collections and performance went up by multiples! Could you please suggest me any other idea to deal this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

I guess your question is about how to use sharding for distributing collections across the nodes? Sharding is actually meant to be a method to meeting the demands of data growth in terms of amount **not number of collections**. That means you partition your collection into multiple shards.

To deal with the issue you are having, you could run multiple instances of `mongod` on the same server that live on their own (not a replica set). You could distribute your collections into these instances. But you will need to hold onto which collection is hosted on which `mongod` process. You would have to store `pid` of each `mongod` processes.

Comment: Colocating multiple mongod's on the same machine - bad idea.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I would say, 3 million collections is a bad idea itself.

Comment: @naimdjon : In this case, should I maintain `mongod` process id's and keep searching them when I want to query the data ?